# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong parent for CardLayout

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, netbeans

I am working to make some simple JFrame things. I am using cardlayout. I got some errors. I am still finding what is problem. It takes more than 6 hours.. I got this error message from eclipse. I use netbeans for making GUI.

```
"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong parent for CardLayout
    at java.awt.CardLayout.checkLayout(CardLayout.java:404)
    at java.awt.CardLayout.show(CardLayout.java:526)
    at RestaurantDemo.actionPerformed(RestaurantDemo.java:379)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)"
```

Java code

```
 public class RestaurantDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    //private CardLayout card; 
    private javax.swing.JFrame tool;
    private java.awt.List allFoodList;
    private javax.swing.JList buyBtn_Others;
    private javax.swing.JButton buyByCardBtn;
    private javax.swing.JButton buyByFoodPointBtn;
    private javax.swing.JPanel card3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField cardNumberField_Others;
    private javax.swing.JTextField cardNumberField_Student;
    private javax.swing.JButton checkBtn;
    private javax.swing.JPanel content;
    private javax.swing.JButton deleteBtn;
    private javax.swing.JButton insertBtn;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    private javax.swing.JButton managerBtn;
    private javax.swing.JPanel managerCard;
    private javax.swing.JButton othersBtn;
    private javax.swing.JPanel othersCard;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField passwordField1_Student;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField passwordField2_Student;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField passwordField_Others;
    private java.awt.List providedFoodList;
    private javax.swing.JList providedFoodList_Student;
    private javax.swing.JList soldFoodList;
    private javax.swing.JButton studentBtn;
    private javax.swing.JTextField studentNumberField;
    private javax.swing.JPanel toolBar;

    public RestaurantDemo() {
        initComponents();
        managerBtn.addActionListener(this);
        tool.setSize(500,500);
        tool.setVisible(true);
        tool.setResizable(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        RestaurantDemo a = new RestaurantDemo();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        tool = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        content = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        othersCard = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        cardNumberField_Others = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        passwordField_Others = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        buyBtn_Others = new javax.swing.JList();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        card3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        providedFoodList_Student = new javax.swing.JList();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        cardNumberField_Student = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        studentNumberField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        passwordField1_Student = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        passwordField2_Student = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        buyByCardBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        buyByFoodPointBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        managerCard = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        allFoodList = new java.awt.List();
        providedFoodList = new java.awt.List();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        soldFoodList = new javax.swing.JList();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        checkBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        insertBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        deleteBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        toolBar = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        managerBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        othersBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        studentBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //CardLayout card = ;
        content.setLayout(new CardLayout());

        jLabel2.setText("card number : ");

        jLabel3.setText("pw:");

        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(buyBtn_Others);

        jButton1.setText("buy");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout othersCardLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(othersCard);
        othersCard.setLayout(othersCardLayout);
        othersCardLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            othersCardLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(othersCardLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(othersCardLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(othersCardLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                        .addGroup(othersCardLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(othersCardLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(passwordField_Others, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 162, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(cardNumberField_Others))
                        .addGap(27, 27, 27))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, othersCardLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(63, 63, 63)))
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 145, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        othersCardLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            othersCardLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(othersCardLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(othersCardLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(othersCardLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(100, 100, 100)
                        .addGroup(othersCardLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(cardNumberField_Others, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(15, 15, 15)
                        .addGroup(othersCardLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(passwordField_Others, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3))
                        .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                    .addGroup(othersCardLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 340, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(19, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        content.add(othersCard, "card3");

        jScrollPane3.setViewportView(providedFoodList_Student);

        jLabel4.setText("card : ");

        jLabel5.setText("pw : ");

        jLabel6.setText("number : ");

        jLabel7.setText("pw2 : ");

        studentNumberField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                studentNumberFieldActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        buyByCardBtn.setText("카드 결제");

        buyByFoodPointBtn.setText("푸드포인트 결제");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout card3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(card3);
        card3.setLayout(card3Layout);
        card3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            card3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(card3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(card3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(card3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                        .addGroup(card3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel6)
                            .addComponent(jLabel7)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(card3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(cardNumberField_Student)
                            .addComponent(studentNumberField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 145, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(passwordField1_Student)
                            .addComponent(passwordField2_Student)
                            .addGroup(card3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                                .addComponent(buyByCardBtn)))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 38, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, card3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(buyByFoodPointBtn)
                        .addGap(50, 50, 50)))
                .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 144, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        card3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            card3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(card3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(card3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(card3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 340, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(card3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(66, 66, 66)
                        .addGroup(card3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addComponent(cardNumberField_Student, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(card3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)
                            .addComponent(passwordField1_Student, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(buyByCardBtn)
                        .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                        .addGroup(card3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel6)
                            .addComponent(studentNumberField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(card3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel7)
                            .addComponent(passwordField2_Student, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(buyByFoodPointBtn)))
                .addContainerGap(19, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        content.add(card3, "card4");

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(soldFoodList);

        jLabel1.setText("list");

        checkBtn.setText("sure");

        insertBtn.setText("add");

        deleteBtn.setText("delete");

        jLabel8.setText("menue");

        jLabel9.setText("mnue2");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout managerCardLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(managerCard);
        managerCard.setLayout(managerCardLayout);
        managerCardLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            managerCardLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(managerCardLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(managerCardLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(managerCardLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(allFoodList, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(managerCardLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                        .addComponent(insertBtn)))
                .addGroup(managerCardLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(managerCardLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                        .addComponent(providedFoodList, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(managerCardLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(48, 48, 48)
                        .addComponent(deleteBtn)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 69, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(managerCardLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, managerCardLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 105, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(27, 27, 27))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, managerCardLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(checkBtn)
                        .addGap(52, 52, 52))))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, managerCardLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(jLabel8)
                .addGap(55, 55, 55)
                .addComponent(jLabel9)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(58, 58, 58))
        );
        managerCardLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            managerCardLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(managerCardLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                .addGroup(managerCardLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel8)
                    .addComponent(jLabel9))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(managerCardLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 250, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(allFoodList, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(providedFoodList, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(13, 13, 13)
                .addGroup(managerCardLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(checkBtn)
                    .addGroup(managerCardLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(insertBtn)
                        .addComponent(deleteBtn)))
                .addContainerGap(42, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        content.add(managerCard, "card2");

        tool.add(content, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        toolBar.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 153));

        managerBtn.setText("manager");
        managerBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                managerBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        othersBtn.setText("other");

        studentBtn.setText("student");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout toolBarLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(toolBar);
        toolBar.setLayout(toolBarLayout);
        toolBarLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            toolBarLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(toolBarLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                .addComponent(managerBtn)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(othersBtn)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(studentBtn)
                .addContainerGap(186, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        toolBarLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            toolBarLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, toolBarLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(toolBarLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(managerBtn)
                    .addComponent(othersBtn)
                    .addComponent(studentBtn))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        tool.add(toolBar, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void managerBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                          

    private void studentNumberFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CardLayout card = (CardLayout)(content.getLayout());
        Object eventSource = e.getSource();
        //Object eventSource = null;
        if(eventSource ==  managerBtn) {
            //System.out.println("aa"); 
            card.show(tool ,"card1");

        } 

    }                                              

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> wrong parent for CardLayout

That is telling you that you did not specify the "panel" that uses that card layout. In your code you have a `setLayout( new CardLayout() )` statement to set the layout for the specified variable.

> at RestaurantDemo.actionPerformed(RestaurantDemo.java:379)

That tells you the statement that is causing the problem.

The `show(...)` method at that statement must refence the same variable from above where you set the card layout.

Finally, some general advice. Use meaningful names:

```
    content.add(managerCard, "card2");
```

In your code you use "card1", "card2", "card3"... Those names mean nothing and will lead to errors. Use more meaningful names, maybe something like "ManagerCard", so you don't have to guess what "card2" means. Better yet, declare static variables in your program so you can use the variable instead of the literal value throughout your code.